# Line up shapes to have coincident edges Visio VBA

Tags: vba, visio

I have used VBA in the past mostly with excel, but I am not very experienced.

I want to cycle through multiple boxes and make each of them have coincident edges. Like they are sitting on top of each other. I am having trouble identifying the position of the first shape in my selection. I've tried a number of different objects including selection.shaperange.

```
    Dim shp As Visio.Shape
    Dim shp1 As Visio.Shape
    Dim Pos As Double
    Set shp1 = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Item
    Pos = shp1.Cells("PinY")

    For Each shp In Application.ActiveWindow.Selection
            'Change the cell name to the one you want
        If shp <> ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1) Then
            Pos = Pos + 6
        End If

        shp.CellsSRC(visSectionControls, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinY).FormulaU = Pos & "mm"
        Pos = shp.Cells("PinY")
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Can you help me get the position of the first selected item and then I may be able to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

This code will abut the left sides of all but the first-selected shape with the right side of the first-selected shape:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AbutLeftsToPrimaryRight()

  Dim sel As Visio.Selection
  Set sel = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection

  If (sel.Count < 2) Then
    Debug.Print "Select two or more shapes (Use Shift + Click)!"
    GoTo Cleanup
  End If

  Dim shp0 As Visio.Shape
  Dim shp As Visio.Shape

  '// Get the selection and the primary selected shape,
  '// which is item(1). See also: Selection.PrimaryItem
  Set shp0 = sel(1)

  '// Quick calculate the right side of shp0:
  '// PinX - LocPinX + Width.
  Dim dRight0 As Double
  dRight0 = shp0.CellsU("PinX").ResultIU - shp0.CellsU("LocPinX").ResultIU + shp0.CellsU("Width").ResultIU

  '// If shapes are rotated, flipped, or not rectangular,
  '// then you'll need to use shp.BoundingBox, which
  '// is more complicated

  Dim dLeft As Double
  Dim dx As Double, px As Double
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 2 To sel.Count

    '// Get the ith shape:
    Set shp = sel(i)

    '// Get its Pin:
    px = shp.CellsU("PinX").ResultIU

    '// Calculate the left side of the shape:
    '// PinX - LocPinX:
    dLeft = px - shp.CellsU("LocPinX").ResultIU

    '// The offset:
    dx = dLeft - dRight0

    '// Set the new pin:
    shp.CellsU("PinX").ResultIUForce = px - dx

  Next i

Cleanup:
  Set shp0 = Nothing
  Set shp = Nothing
  Set sel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!